# `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values

Tags: reactjs, image, svg, slider

i have this error when creating a before,after image slider in react.
i dont know if there will be need for me to import it, but unfuntunately it is an external file.
any tip and suggestion will be appreciated

```
<div class="scroller scroller-top">
                    <svg class="scroller__thumb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100"   height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" style="fill:rgb(24,24,62)"/><polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" style="fill:rgb(24,24,62)"/></svg>
</div>
```

i am expecting the svg icon but an error was thrown instead as seen in the description above

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `fill` prop directly on the polygon like below:

```
<div className="scroller scroller-top">
  <svg
    className="scroller__thumb"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="100"
    height="100"
    viewBox="0 0 100 100"
  >
    <polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" fill="rgb(24,24,62)" />
    <polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" fill="rgb(24,24,62)" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Bonus: If you're using React, the `class` attribute should be `className`.

Comment: Thanks that solved it, the **class was a mistake on my path, it should be className instead** 
I was trying to convert my project from vanilla to react. however, your solution solved the style prop issue.
**which was to remove the nested style**